# Creating a Session in javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, session

I need to create a Session in javascript function, but i don't know how... Can someone help me?

Thank you!

This is the code-

```
function DeleteBook(idimg) {
// idimg is a string
            var userConfirm = window.confirm('Are you sure?');

            if (userConfirm == true) {

                Session["forDelete"] = a; //doesn't work
                window.open('Delete.aspx');
            }
            else
                return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a Session in javascript, Session is made on Server Side.

What you can do is send an ajax call with the value which you want to place in Session and create it on Server Side.

you can do like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Default.aspx/SetSession",
  data: "{MyValue:a}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});
```

and server side:

```
public partial class Default : Page 
{
  [WebMethod]
  public static string SetSession(string MyValue)
  {
    Session["forDelete"] = MyValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: I did a Session in javascript function, but I cann't add to a session an object.

Comment: you can get value from Session in js but cannot set

Comment: you are in webforms of mvc

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a call to the server in your javascript function. Then you can create a session on the back end.

Assuming .net (from tag)

```
Session["MySession"] = ...;
```

Comment: How can I cell to the server?

Comment: @user3526787 I don't know the exact technology you're using, but you can make an ajax call and pass the data as a json object.